# VBA copy and paste code not working

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I am trying to copy column from one sheet to another. To avoid 'Select', I wrote code like worksheet.range.copy. For some reason, code below is giving me error. If I replace Range("A2").End(xlDown) with lets say "A100" then code will work.

```
Sub CopyData()

    MTDData.Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Copy
    MTDFormula.Range("H2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

End Sub
```

Any suggestion why the code above giving error and is there a more efficient way to copy and paste large chunk of data from one sheet to another.[image]

Comment: Counting rows is so easy to mess up. See my answer for a reusable function that checks for empty cells or singular values. In your case the typo in your code is fixed with `MTDData.Range("A2", MTDData.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Copy`

Comment: Got it. Can you please also tell me what wrong with the code below 
 MTDData.Range(Cells(2, 10), Cells(CellsCount, 10)).Copy

Comment: `Cells()` assumes `ActiveWorksheet`. I suggest to use `.Cells()` only after a `Range()` object. Like `MTData.Range("A2").Cells(2,10)` that gets the 2nd row and 10 column starting from `A2`. To get multiple cells (like whole column, or a whole table) use the `.Resize(nrows,ncols)` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way to copy large sets of values is *not to use the clipboard* but the copy directly.

```
MTDFormula.Range("H2").Resize(n,1).Value = MTDData.Range("A2").Resize(n,1).Value
```

but you have to find the size of the cells first. This is done with the following reusable piece of code:

```
Public Function CountRows(ByRef r As Range) As Long
    If IsEmpty(r) Then
        CountRows = 0
    ElseIf IsEmpty(r.Offset(1, 0)) Then
        CountRows = 1
    Else
        CountRows = r.Worksheet.Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    End If
End Function
```

So your copying code would look like this:

```
Public Sub CopyValuesTest()

    Dim src As Range, dst As Range

    Set src = MTDData.Range("A2")
    Set dst = MTDFormula.Range("H2")

    Dim n As Long
    n = CountRows(src)

    dst.Resize(n, 1).Value = src.Resize(n, 1).Value
    dst.Resize(n, 1).NumberFormat = src.Resize(n, 1).NumberFormat
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the parent sheet to the range inside the range:

```
MTDData.Range("A2", MTDData.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Copy
MTDFormula.Range("H2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

But we can use a `With` block and save some typing and space.  Also you do not need the pastespecial.

```
With MTDData
    .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Copy MTDFormula.Range("H2")
End with
```